# How to set an option as selected in a dynamically generated select control using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I set an option as selected in a dynamically generated select control using jQuery?

I'm trying to build a little car search with dynamic select fields [so that a user can never select a set of options that result in no results!] using php, jquery, ajax

Right now I'm just feeding the ajax a static array populated with php:

```
$output = array(
    'make' => array(
        'GMC' => '',
        'Chevy' => 'selected',
        'NISSAN' => '',
    ), 
    'model' => array(
        'Canyon' => '',
        'Tahoe' => 'selected',
        'Avalance' => '',
    ), 
    'year' => array(
        '2009' => '',
        '2010' => 'selected',
        '2011' => '',
    ), 
    'type' => array(
        'Truck' => '',
        'Mini Van' => 'selected',
        'Compact' => '',
    ), 
);

$output = $modx->toJSON($output);
```

which works fine, we can see everything coming through in the console,

Then we have the javascript for it:

$('.filter-group').change(function() {

```
var form = $('#searchform');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //url: form.attr( 'action' ),
    url: '[[~131]]',
    data: form.serialize(),
    dataType  : "json",
    cache: false,


    beforeSend: function() {
        console.log( 'before send' );
    },

    success: function(data, status) {

        $.each(data, function( key, value ) {

        console.log(key);

        populateSelectControls(key, value);

        });

    },

    error: function(data){
        //this would be a 404 error!    
        console.log('hellooo - this is an error!!!');
    }
});
```

});

function populateSelectControls(optKey, optValues){

```
var $control = $('#' + optKey);

$control.empty(); 

$control.append($("<option></option>").text('Select ' + optKey));

$.each(optValues, function(key, value) {

    console.log('key = ' + key + ' value = ' + value);

    var mycontrol = $control.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", '.'+key).text(key));

    if (value === 'selected') {

        alert(key + ' is selected');
        mycontrol.attr('selected','selected'); // this is the problem

    };

});
```

}

The problem comes with how to set an option as selected, I can't seem to figure that one out. The alert pops up but I don't know how to set the current option in the loop to selected.

how is this done?

Comment: try `mycontrol.prop('selected', true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) it returns the elements to which the target element is returned not the appended element(in your case the `select` element not the newly added `option` element). So the statement `mycontrol.attr('selected','selected');` does not have any effect.

You need to set the selected property on the newly created `option` element, to do that you can use [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) like

```
function populateSelectControls(optKey, optValues) {
    var $control = $('#' + optKey);

    $control.empty();

    $control.append($("<option></option>").text('Select ' + optKey));

    $.each(optValues, function (key, value) {

        //the problem is here, in your case mycontrol was referring to the select not the added option
        $("<option />", {
            value: '.' + key,
            text: key,
            selected: value === 'selected'
        }).appendTo($control);

    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ougd4kxm/)